# Traversing the DOM tree with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="media">

    <div class="pull-left">

    </div>

    <div class="media-body">

        <div class="content">

        </div>

        <div class="news">

            <div class="sub">

            </div>

            <!-- insert here -->

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="current">

</div>
```

I am trying to traverse the DOM tree using jQuery. My DOM is described above. My starting point is `id="current"`. I'd like to insert some data where I have written `<!-- insert here -->`

So far I've tried this which didn't work: `$(data).appendTo($("#current").prev("div"));`. Hoping somebody can help?

**Please note**: I have multiple `.media`, `.pull-left`, `.media-body`, `.content`, `.news` and `.sub` divs elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Which `.media .media-body .news` div will you be targeting? Will it always be the first, the last, or is it determined in some other way? Without knowing we really can't help.

Comment: @winterblood the .media .media-body .news div I want to target will always be the previous sibling to #current - exactly as it's shown in the question code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(data).appendTo($("#current").parent().find(".news"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pLCq/1/

Comment: Shredder you nailed it. Thank you

Comment: @henrywright This will append to every sibling element with class equal to `news`, I was under the impression you only wanted it appended to the previous sibling?

Comment: Yeah, there should only be one `.news` in the parent container of `#current` for this to work. If there are more, let me know how..and we can get a little more specific.

Comment: @winterblood good point! I can still use Shredder's answer + a work around to achieve what I need. But feel free to provide an answer if you know of one as anyone else coming to the question might find it useful. Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 2):

To append only to the previous sibling's ancestor with class equal to `news` try the following:

```
$(data).appendTo($("#current").prev(".media").first().find(".news"));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pLCq/3/)

Comment: +1 as this answers my question perfectly. Thanks again!